# How to Remove the whole line with a matching pattern exists only in the column range 75 to 104

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a file which contains data in the below form.

```
507425B30    171013D248900022   4057-ACCR PROPERTY TAX  
00000000257910+00000000000000+00000000257910+00000000000000+00000000000000+
507425B30    171013C249999092   1071-DO NOT USE         
00000000000000+00000000000000+00000000000000+00000000031940+00000000000000+
```

Now i have to delete the lines which contains the pattern like 
00000000000000+00000000000000+ and the tricky part is that we have to delete 
the line only when it comes in the 1st occurrence. There will be scenarios 
like the first record in the above where the pattern came at the last and it 
should not delete the line from the file. I tried using the below command 
but it is deleting the line when it finds that pattern in the last which 
shouldn't be the case.

```
sed '/00000000000000+00000000000000+/d' file
```

I have written the below code to fix this issue. But it seems it is going to the Infinite loop. Can you help where i am going wrong?

```
while read line
do
x=`cat $Line | cut -c 75-104`
echo $x

if [ $x -eq "00000000000000+00000000000000+" ]
then
sed  '/00000000000000+00000000000000+/d' $File > File.dat
fi

done < $File
```

Comment: In regex we use the `^` to denote that the character sequence we are searching for exists at the beginning of the line, so `sed '/^00000000000000\+00000000000000\+/d' file ` should do the trick (I've also escaped those plus signs since those are control characters in regex.

Comment: It's not deleting anything. The output file is same as the input file after running that command.

Comment: sed outputs to stdout. If you want the file itself to be subject to the deletions you need to use the `-i` flag for "Edit in place": `sed -i '/^00000000000000\+00000000000000\+/d' file`

Comment: Oh! it looks like my attempt to escape those plusses is causing an issue. Try `sed '/^00000000000000+00000000000000+/d' file`  That should do the trick.

Comment: JNevill. I have tried this and the same issue ...

Comment: In the question heading, you have mentioned about column range 75 to 104.  But, in the body, you have never mentioned about this.  Actually, do you want to ignore the pattern starting from beginning of the line or positioned at column 75 to 104 ? Please clarify.

Comment: Hi Alvin. You can ignore the column range. I need to  delete the whole row when this pattern 00000000000000+00000000000000+ appears in the file. The tricky part is it uld delete the row only when the pattern appears in the first. For example in the first record which I posted in the question the pattern appears in the last and hence it shouldn't delete the row.....

Comment: Hi. I have included my piece of code in the original Post. Could some one take a look at that and let me know if  I am missing anything there?

Answer (score 0):

This will remove every line of 'file' that begin with 14 zeros and a plus char two times.

```
sed -i '/^[0]\{14\}+[0]\{14\}+/d' file
```

Comment: It's still not changing anything. I am getting the output same as input...